# Is there a way to use map and getElementById to make these objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I'm trying to build a tool to create boilerplate evaluations for students.

```
import React from 'react'

function ScoresList(props) {
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    for (let i = 0; i < props.studentList.length; i++) {
      props.studentList[i].grade = document.getElementById('grade').value
      console.log(props.studentList[i])
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <ul>
          {props.studentList.map((Student) => (
            <li key={Student.firstName}>
              {Student.firstName} {Student.lastName} Grade:{' '}
              <select id="grade">
                <option value="9th">9th</option>
                <option value="10th">10th</option>
                <option value="11th">11th</option>
                <option value="12th">12th</option>
              </select>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ScoresList
```

This component is supposed to output a list of the students input on the first page and then the teacher is will fill in all the options. When it's done the teacher should have about 25 different boxes to fill in per student. Right now I only have one there while I try to get it to work.

I tried using getElementById.elements but the elements keep coming back undefined. I'm not sure how to get the values where I need them.

studentsList is an array of objects that it creates on the first page. That's passed down okay because I can get it to log it to the console. It has an attribute for grade.

```
const Student = function (
    firstName,
    lastName,
    grade,
    currentClass,
    setting,
    yearGrade,
    q1,
    q2,
    q3,
    absent,
    tardy,
    pronouns,
    focus,
    askQuestions,
    turnInWork,
    intellegence,
    distraction,
    selfStarter,
    perseverence,
    bestModeOfLearning,
    socialInteractions,
    fluencyWithTechnology,
    camera,
    responsivenessOnline,
    language,
    placement,
    result
  ) {
    this.firstName = firstName
    this.lastName = lastName
    this.grade = grade
    this.currentClass = currentClass
    this.setting = setting
    this.yearGrade = yearGrade
    this.q1 = q1
    this.q2 = q2
    this.q3 = q3
    this.absent = absent
    this.tardy = tardy
    this.pronouns = pronouns
    this.focus = focus
    this.askQuestions = askQuestions
    this.turnInWork = turnInWork
    this.intellegence = intellegence
    this.distraction = distraction
    this.selfStarter = selfStarter
    this.perseverence = perseverence
    this.bestModeOfLearning = bestModeOfLearning
    this.socialInteractions = socialInteractions
    this.fluencyWithTechnology = fluencyWithTechnology
    this.camera = camera
    this.responsivenessOnline = responsivenessOnline
    this.language = language
    this.placement = placement
    this.result = result
```

This is the object I wrote.

Comment: How does the object need to be structured? This is definitely possible but we need more information.

Comment: With React you want to avoid using any DOM manipulation like `getElementById` because it goes against how React operates. Instead you rely on states, where states decide how the content should be rendered.

Comment: I added the object I wrote. If you think I need to change to make it work that's fine. I haven't written out the function to create the result so it doesn't matter from that standpoint.

Comment: You should consider revising your function to take an object with those various arguments as parameters of the object, that many arguments is untenable

Comment: @Dexygen I'm not entirely sure how to do that. I tried researching it and I'm not finding anything useful.